# How to group data to have approximately the same summation regardless number of member

Tags: python

How to make summation of a group to be almost identical regardless number of member per group

ie.

```
input -> ('a', 100), ('b', 200), ('c', 300), ('d', 50), ('e', 200), ('f', 50)

output

group A ->  (a,100) , (b,200)  
group B ->  (c,300)            
group C ->  (d,50) , (e,200), (f,50)
```

each group got total sum of 300

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [('a', 100), ('b', 200)]
b = [('c', 300)]
c = [('d', 50), ('e', 200), ('f', 50)]

group = []
for i in [a, b, c]:
    k = 0
    for j in i:
        k += j[1]
    group.append(k)
# or
group = [sum([j[1] for j in i]) for i in [a, b, c]]
print(group)
```

It shows you how many number of member in each group, if it different you can change you data. It would be better if you provider your code

Comment: Sorry to have ambiguous question. I mean how to dynamically assign member to N group to achieve almost identical summation without need to have the same number of member in each group